# Study data science at university

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, data-analysis, ai, chatbot

**Is it a waste to study data science in university, despite the advancement of artificial intelligence and automation of analysis?**
regards

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not it's a **waste** of your time and resource significantly depends on the rigor of the course and how up to date it is with current technologies and advances in data science.

Online courses could be a great way to self-teach data science. However, it often comes with the compromise of not teaching you enough of the relevant math. While you might get away with not knowing the math for a lot of the applications you might encounter, you will most definitely be missing out crucial insights. *The math matters*.

Recently, many universities have been updating their applied CS related courses to the latest technologies. And universities will most likely have an emphasis on math compared to online resources. If this happens to be the case, a university course will definitely be the better choice.

In conclusion, the *best choice* depends on the specifics of the particular course in question and what you want to achieve by learning that material. A general answer to your question is not possible as of present, but it might be in the future; and given my personal observations of the current trend, I'd bet my money on university offered courses (which may or may not be online) rather than other online resources.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I studied statistics for my bachelor's degree and decided to study data science for my master's degree.  But the recent issues (such as chatgpt, etc.) that announce the automation of data science tasks, made me hesitate for this choice.